# How to apply a formula for removing data noise in R?

Tags: function, r, noise

I am working on NGSim Traffic data, having 18 columns and 1180598 rows in a text file. I want to smooth the position data, in the column 'Local Y'. I know there are built-in functions for data smoothing in R but none of them seem  to match with the formula I am required to apply. The data in text file looks something like this:

```
Index   VehicleID   Total_Frames    Local Y

    1   2   5   35.381
    2   2   5   39.381
    3   2   5   43.381
    4   2   5   47.38
    5   2   5   51.381
    6   4   8   504.828
    7   4   8   508.325
    8   4   8   512.841
    9   4   8   516.338
    10  4   8   520.854
    11  4   8   524.592
    12  4   8   528.682
    13  4   8   532.901
    14  5   7   39.154
    15  5   7   43.153
    16  5   7   47.154
    17  5   7   51.154
    18  5   7   55.153
    19  5   7   59.154
    20  5   7   63.154
```

The above data columns are just example taken out of original file. Here you can see 3 vehicles, with vehicle IDs = 2, 4 and 5 but in fact there are 2169 vehicles with different IDS. The column Total_Frames tell us how many times vehicle Id of each vehicle is repeated in the first column, for example in the table above, vehicle ID 2 is repeated 5 times, hence '5' in Total_Frames column. Following is the formula I am required to apply to remove data noise (smoothing) from column 'Local Y':

Smoothed Position Value = (1/(Summation of [EXP^-abs(i-k)/delta] from k=i-D to i+D)) * ( (Summation of (Local Y) *[EXP^-abs(i-k)/delta] from k=i-D to i+D))

where,

i = index #
delta  = 5
D = 15

I have tried using the built-in functions, which I know of, but they don't smooth the data as required. My question is: Is there any built-in function in R which can do the data smoothing in the way of given formula or which could take this formula as an argument? I need to apply the formula to every value in Local Y which has 15 values before and 15 values after them (i-D and i+D)  for same vehicle Id. Can anyone give me any idea how to approach the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is better suited for stackoverflow. If I read your smoothing function correctly, the summation cancels out and only `Local Y` is left (notice that you can drop the top-level parens). Is there an error somewhere? Also, what existing R functions did you already try?

Answer (score 0):

You can place your formula in a function and then use the apply function of R to apply it to the elements in your "Local Y" column of the dataframe

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can use apply function, but as you can see, the formula has to be applied on all Local Y values EXCEPT the first and last 15 values for every vehicle ID. In the example provided above, if I want to apply formula on all local Y values leaving the first two and last two values for every vehicle ID (2,4,5) how can I do that?